# I have a variable in C++ that says its undefined, when clearly defined in my constructor. C++

Tags: c++

Constructor is here:

When I declare my `setLeft()` function, it tells me `m_pLeft` is not defined. I've tried moving it all over the place and can't get it to say it's anything other than undefined.

SetLeft is defined as
    void setLeft(BookRecord *leftpointer){
        *m_pLeft = *leftpointer;
    }

```
#pragma once
class BookRecord
    {
    private:
        char m_sName[100]; //unique names for each book
        long m_lStockNum; //a stock number, similar to a barcode
        int m_iClassification; //how a book should be classified, similar to a dewey decimal system
        double m_dCost; //The price of the book
        int m_iCount; //How many books are in stock
        BookRecord *m_pLeft; //Left pointer for the tree
        BookRecord *m_pRight; //right Pointer from the tree

    public:
        BookRecord(void);
        BookRecord(char *name,long sn, int cl,double cost);
        ~BookRecord();
        void getName(char *name);
        void setName(char *Sname);
        long getStockNum();
        void setStockNum(long sn);
        void getClassification(int& cl);
        void setClassification(int cl);
        double getCost();
        void setCost(double c);
        int getNumberInStock();
        void setNumberInStock(int count);
        void printRecord();
        BookRecord getLeft();
        BookRecord getRight();
        void setLeft(BookRecord *leftpointer);
        void setRight(BookRecord *rightpointer);
    };
```

Comment: need to use `BookRecord*`, as it is a pointer

Comment: It's just a class that holds individual objects of books. The actual implementation of storing the records is held within a different class. and they have asterisks, it just didn't copy over for some reason.

Comment: You clearly say there is an error reported in `setLeft`.  Then you do not show us the body/implementation of `setLeft`.  Why??

Answer (score 3):

> When I declare my `setLeft()` function, it tells me `m_pLeft` is not defined.

The error that you see is not coming from the *declaration* of `setLeft()` member function, but from its *definition* (the declaration is not referencing `m_pLeft`):

```
// This is incorrect - it will not compile
void setLeft(BookRecord *leftpointer) {
    m_pLeft = leftpointer;
}
```

The problem with a definition like this is that the compiler treats it like a free-standing function, so `m_pLeft` member is not in scope. You need to tell the compiler that you are defining a member function, like this:

```
// This will compile
void BookRecord::setLeft(BookRecord *leftpointer) {
    m_pLeft = leftpointer;
}
```